# HTML unordered list bullets and floating div's inside li on Webkit

Tags: html, webkit, css-float, html-lists

I have a simple unordered list with list-style-type: disc and with some li's that have each two floated div's. The problem is that only on Webkit browsers (Safari, Chrome...) the bullets appear to the right side of the list.

See attached screenshot and this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tudor2004/JjrU3/)

Here is the code:

```
<ul>
    <li class="cf">
        <span class="left">Text1:</span>
        <span class="left">00,00 &euro;</span>
    </li>

    <li>
        <span class="left">Text2:</span>
        <span class="left">00,00 &euro;</span>
    </li>

    <li>
        <span class="left">Text3:</span>
        <span class="left">00,00 &euro;</span>
    </li>

    <li>
        <span class="left">Text4:</span>
        <span class="left">00,00 &euro;</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can't tell you anything without seeing CSS of classes `cf` and `left`

Comment: cf is just the clearfix, it isn't added in the jsfiddle  so even removing that class the bug is still there. (the class is from the original code, i forgot to remove it).

Comment: If you change `float:left` to `display:inline-block` it works properly, but I don't know if you are avoiding this property with reasons... hope this helps any case ;)

Comment: @Arkana Thank you! Using display inline-block helps a lot. The problem is that IE7-IE8 doesn't support inline-block, but i think i will use a css hack for this. How can I mark up your comment as "right answer"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I say in the comments you could try with: `display:inline-block;`

Here's a [**working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/JjrU3/5/).

If you want IE7 support, add in you only-IE7 css `display:inline`. That makes IE7 understand the inline-block.

If you are using only one css you could try: `*:first-child + html ul li {display:inline;} /* only for IE7 */`

IE8 supports inline-block properly ;)

Comment: ok, we posted on the same time (my reply to you last comment and your answer). thanx again

Comment: Instead of a star hack or something try using the sample code for IE7, it pass the validator :)

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding, you want the float on the `ul li`, not the `ul li .left`, and then adding `float: left` so that each item appears on a different line. Otherwise it causes the content of each li to float to the left past the bullet.

Updated jsfiddle with the float move to `ul li`: http://jsfiddle.net/JjrU3/3/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is not what I try to obtain. The two span's inside each li should be floated, because they need to be all aligned, the text one under the other and the price one under the other. Also the list should have bullets. If you open the fiddle in Firefox you can see that the behavior is OK, but the problem appears only on Webkit browsers.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to mimic columns, use a `display: inline-block` on your `ul li.left` instead of the `float: left`. You would have to be sure that the width of your li equals its highest content. Otherwise the columns will overlap

[the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JjrU3/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Two span floating there will be a bug，so you define the first span with float,the second span with display:inline-block. 
and you can use display for span:

```
ul li .leaf {display:inline-block}
```