# webkit shows bullet behind floated elements in list

Tags: html, css

```css
span {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>test</span></li>
</ul>
```

Have a look at this in firefox vs chrome, chrome will show the bullet after the floated span element.

I'm not really sure what is happening here, seems the float is escaping the list item in webkit. Anyone come across this and know a solution?

Comment: This is a very old WebKit bug - floats interfere greatly with list bullets for some reason.

Comment: not sure if its a solution but you can  use a p tag and take up the span using margin-top -- https://jsfiddle.net/btc6ydab/

Comment: Reference to bug: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=89829

Comment: bullets could be produce via a css counter , choosing any image or text to show

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out by @silviagreen this is a [webkit-specific bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=89829) but as a workaround I suggest to add a transparent border to the list-item. This seems to properly work (but I honestly admit that I can't figure out why this should work)

```
li {
   border: 1px transparent solid;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rjkz7ny1/

---

Other approaches [suggest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17018792/html-unordered-list-bullets-and-floating-divs-inside-li-on-webkit) to change `float: left` into `display: inline-block` or to give `clear: left` to the list, but I feel these workarounds a bit too substantial (and not always appliable) than adding a trasparent border.

Comment: Clever! I'd love to know why this works. Did you discover this yourself or is it a known fix for float issues?

Comment: @Stef I've just discovered it playing around the OP's fiddle. I've also tried a bunch of other properties with no luck

Comment: @Stef: "I'd love to know why this works." Because it's WebKit ;)

Comment: Well kudos to you! How you even thought to try that is mind boggling. @BoltClock LOL

Comment: So weird. Specifically, it's `border-top`, or `padding-top`.

Comment: But in all seriousness, I have reason to believe WebKit's implementation of `display: list-item` is way, *way* off. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21769248/list-with-nested-overflow-x-hidden-hides-list-counter-point-why-is-this-a-b/21778308#21778308 for an example of another WebKit list-item bug where I explain my theory. cc @Stef

Answer (score 0):

A pseudo element, with a CSS `counter` for `ol` list can be used to avoid bug and use of `border`s

```css
span {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
}
ol {
  counter-reset:marker;
  }
li {
  counter-increment:marker;
  list-style-type:none;
  box-shadow:0 2px gray;
  }
li:before {
  content:'\02022 ';
  padding-right:0.25em;
  float:left;
  }
ol li:before {
  content:counter(marker)'. ';
  }
hr ~* li:before {
  text-indent:-1em;
  }
li:after {
  content:'';
  display:table;
  clear:both;
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>test</span></li>
  <li><span>test</span></li>
</ul>
<ol>
  <li><span>test</span></li>
  <li><span>test</span></li>
</ol>
<hr/>
<ul>
  <li><span>test</span></li>
  <li><span>test</span></li>
</ul>
<ol>
  <li><span>test</span></li>
  <li><span>test</span></li>
</ol>
```